# Unable to understand how header files work?

Tags: c++, header, header-files, tensorflow

I am not sure how to properly frame by question but I will try. I have cloned tensorflow repository on my pc and I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/lib/core/stringpiece.cc) file.
So I added the following lines to the end of the program

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  tensorflow::StringPiece s20("hello");
  std:: cout << s20.data() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Then I get the error

```
stringpiece.cc:16:50: fatal error: tensorflow/core/lib/core/stringpiece.h: No such file or directory
 #include "tensorflow/core/lib/core/stringpiece.h"
                                                  ^
compilation terminated.
```

I can make the code work when I take all the related header files and put them in a separate folder and make a few changes to headers but how can I make this work directly. I also need to understand how

```
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/core/stringpiece.h"
```

works.
Basically what I am trying to say is that,I want to run specific subparts of the C++ API without affecting the headers at all.  And yes I have installed tensorflow and its working.

Comment: Did you install the library?

Comment: You are using Bazel of course?

Comment: I have installed the library and its working. This is completely different though.

Comment: Does #include <tensorflow....> work? The <> and "" operate with different paths resulting in a different file lookup where "" is starting in the project directory and <> is starting at wherever the system include path is.

Comment: @ArafatK Where is the tensorflow directory located relative to your project directory? What environment are you in (windows / linux / osx)? The error message is saying that <project paths>/tensorflow/core/lib/core/stringpiece.h is not found. There are ways to fix this, but it depends on the system. If you're using gcc you could add the compiler option -I<path> where <path> = the absolute path location of where the tensorflow directory exists. In MSVC++ you'll have to do something different.

Comment: Thanks it works. I am getting the error 
     /tmp/ccag4ztO.o: In function `tensorflow::Hash64(char const*, unsigned long)':
stringpiece.cc:(.text._ZN10tensorflow6Hash64EPKcm[_ZN10tensorflow6Hash64EPKcm]+0x29): undefined reference to `tensorflow::Hash64(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

But I am sure its a different issue. I just have one question. Is it even possible to run files like this way ?

Comment: @ArafatK Possible to run files how? It appears as though you are attempting to use parts of the tensorflow library without pulling in everything from the library. If it's opensource it's possible. You'll need to pull in the source files containing the functionality you use into your project along with any of it's dependencies, or otherwise pull out the functionality you want into your code base. If it's not open source, and you are dealing with a compiled binary without access to source code, it's all or nothing. This is only detailing how, not if you should of course.

Comment: @Aumnayan Thanks a lot for the help. I just have another question as a follow up to your comment.      And I would really really appreciate if you could help me out on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622713/using-tensorflow-c-shared-library) one.

Comment: this is wayyyy too broad did you google *at all*?